# Set row number for batch of N rows per category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, row-number

I have table

```
+-----+----------+---------+
| id  | name     | phase   |
+-----+----------+---------+
| 101 | Bolt     | PHASE 1 |
| 102 | Nut      | PHASE 1 |
| 103 | Screw    | PHASE 1 |
| 104 | Hex BOLT | PHASE 1 |
| 105 | Rubber   | PHASE 1 |
| 106 | Aluminum | PHASE 2 |
| 107 | Slate    | PHASE 2 |
| 108 | Pen      | PHASE 3 |
| 109 | Pencil   | PHASE 3 |
| 110 | Mouse    | PHASE 3 |
| 111 | Keyboard | PHASE 3 |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

I want to create a another column in which i have to put row number.

Logic :
For 3 rows, it should be same and change to next value for 4th row. And Whenever the PHASE is changing, it should go to next number even if the set of 3 is not complete for the previous number.

Expected Output

```
+-----+----------+---------+-----+
| id  | name     | phase   | SET |
+-----+----------+---------+-----+
| 101 | Bolt     | PHASE 1 | 1   |
| 102 | Nut      | PHASE 1 | 1   |
| 103 | Screw    | PHASE 1 | 1   |
| 104 | Hex BOLT | PHASE 1 | 2   |
| 105 | Rubber   | PHASE 1 | 2   |
| 106 | Aluminum | PHASE 2 | 3   |
| 107 | Slate    | PHASE 2 | 3   |
| 108 | Pen      | PHASE 3 | 4   |
| 109 | Pencil   | PHASE 3 | 4   |
| 110 | Mouse    | PHASE 3 | 4   |
| 111 | Keyboard | PHASE 3 | 5   |
+-----+----------+---------+-----+
```

I have tried the below query, but it is not giving me the required output.

```
select *, (row_number() over (order by phase)-1) / 3 as sets
from table_main
```

Actual Output:

```
+-----+----------+---------+------+
| id  | name     | phase   | sets |
+-----+----------+---------+------+
| 101 | Bolt     | PHASE 1 | 0    |
| 102 | Nut      | PHASE 1 | 0    |
| 103 | Screw    | PHASE 1 | 0    |
| 104 | Hex BOLT | PHASE 1 | 1    |
| 105 | Rubber   | PHASE 1 | 1    |
| 106 | Aluminum | PHASE 2 | 1    |
| 107 | Slate    | PHASE 2 | 2    |
| 108 | Pen      | PHASE 3 | 2    |
| 109 | Pencil   | PHASE 3 | 2    |
| 110 | Mouse    | PHASE 3 | 3    |
| 111 | Keyboard | PHASE 3 | 3    |
+-----+----------+---------+------+
```

I have tried with `DENSE_RANK()` as well but not getting the expected output.

[**FIDDLE HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8be5432401ce24e2afdc56a09b87f3de)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
WITH CTE
as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY phase ORDER BY id) as rn
from table_main
)
SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY phase ,CEILING(rn/3.0)) as set
FROM CTE
```

Comment: This answer is definitely cleaner and easy to understand than my answer.!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get previous row value for `column` and if it changed then add `1`. Use `ROW_NUMBER()` as mentioned with `%3` and then `sum` those values like below.

```
;WITH tm AS (
    SELECT *, 
            IIF((LAG(phase, 1) OVER (ORDER BY phase, id)) = phase, 0, 1) AS phase_change,
            IIF((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY phase ORDER BY phase)-1)%3 = 0, 1, 0) AS [set]
    FROM table_main
) 
SELECT id, 
        name, 
        phase,
        SUM(IIF([set] > phase_change, [set], phase_change)) OVER (ORDER BY phase, id) AS [set]
FROM tm
```